# Weird padding using imakeidx

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, imakeidx, makeindex

I've been using `imakeidx` with the following style (the `index.ist`):

```
headings_flag 1 

heading_prefix "\n\\centering\\large\\sffamily% 
\\noindent\\textbf{"heading_suffix "}\\par\\nopagebreak\n"

item_0 "\n \\item \\small "

delim_0 "\\dotfill"   
delim_1 "\\dotfill"   
delim_2 "\\dotfill"
```

And setting it up with:

```
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[name=street,title=Streets,options=-s ./index]
\makeindex[name=poi,title=Points of Interest,options=-s ./index]

\usepackage[font=small]{idxlayout}
```

And this (in order to, eliminate the hanging left margin from breaking lines, as I read somewhere):

```
\makeatletter
\def\@idxitem{\par\hangindent 0pt}
\makeatother
```

However, the resulting PDF has some weird... artifacts, namely a bizarre left margin/padding, in the case of entries that do not fit.

See this as an example:

[image]

Any ideas what might be going on?

---

Working sample:

**index.ist**

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\n\\centering\\large\\sffamily%
\\noindent\\textbf{"heading_suffix "}\\par\\nopagebreak\n"

item_0 "\n \\item \\small "

delim_0 "\\dotfill"
delim_1 "\\dotfill"
delim_2 "\\dotfill"
```

**test.tex**

```
\documentclass[8pt,twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx,grffile}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[paperwidth=5.125in, 
            paperheight=8.25in, 
            bindingoffset=0.1in,
            inner=0.6in,
            outer=0.7in,
            top=0.6in,
            bottom=1in,
            columnsep=25pt,
            layoutsize={5in,8in},
            layouthoffset=0.125in,
            layoutvoffset=0.25in
            ]
            {geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nobottomtitles*]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=street,title=Streets,options=-s ./index]
\makeindex[name=poi,title=Points of Interest,options=-s ./index]

\usepackage[font=small]{idxlayout}

\makeatletter
\def\@idxitem{\par\hangindent 0pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
PAGE ONE

\index[street]{Avenida de andalucÃ­a}
\index[street]{Avenida de francisco ayala}
\index[street]{Avenida de las alpujarras}
\index[street]{Avenida luis miranda dÃ¡valos}
\index[street]{Calle adoratrices}
\index[street]{Calle algarrobo}
\index[street]{Calle algas}
\index[street]{Calle antonio machado}
\index[street]{Calle apolo}
\index[street]{Calle baza}
\index[street]{Calle brindis}
\index[street]{Calle capote}
\index[street]{Calle chanquete}
\index[street]{Calle chicuelinas}
\index[street]{Calle circunvalaciÃ³n encina}
\index[street]{Calle coso}
\index[street]{Calle curro cÃºchares}
\index[street]{Calle delfÃ­n}
\index[street]{Calle dorada}
\index[street]{Calle encina}
\index[street]{Calle este}
\index[street]{Calle esturiÃ³n}
\index[street]{Calle guadix}
\index[street]{Calle hispanidad}
\index[street]{Calle joseito de granada}
\index[street]{Calle jÃºpiter}
\index[street]{Calle las acacias}
\index[street]{Calle manuel mateos}
\index[street]{Calle marÃ­a lejÃ¡rraga}
\index[street]{Calle mero}
\index[street]{Calle monosabio}
\index[street]{Calle morena}
\index[street]{Calle mulillas}
\index[street]{Calle nerviÃ³n}
\index[street]{Calle norte}
\index[street]{Calle oeste}
\index[street]{Calle pargo}
\index[street]{Calle perete}
\index[street]{Calle periodista antonio lÃ³pez muÃ±oz}
\index[street]{Calle periodista eduardo font moreno}
\index[street]{Calle periodista fernando gÃ³mez de la cruz}
\index[street]{Calle periodista francisco guerrero vÃ­lchez}
\index[street]{Calle periodista francisco javier cobos}
\index[street]{Calle periodista gabriel ruiz de almodÃ³var}
\index[street]{Calle periodista matÃ­as mÃ©ndez vellido}
\index[street]{Calle periodista miguel montalvo jimÃ©nez}
\index[street]{Calle periodista ricardo lÃ³pez jofre}
\index[street]{Calle raya}
\index[street]{Calle rejÃ³n}
\index[street]{Calle salmÃ³n}
\index[street]{Calle sirena}
\index[street]{Calle sur}
\index[street]{Calle teÃ³filo gautier}
\index[street]{Calle tiburÃ³n}
\index[street]{Calle trucha}
\index[street]{Calle veleta}
\index[street]{Calle venus}
\index[street]{Carretera de mÃ¡laga}
\index[street]{Plaza periodista josÃ© marÃ­a gonzalo de la torre}
\index[street]{Plaza periodista ramÃ³n maurell lÃ³pez}
\clearpage

%-------------

\thispagestyle{empty}
PAGE TWO

\index[street]{Avenida de andalucÃ­a}
\index[street]{Avenida de francisco ayala}
\index[street]{Avenida de la constituciÃ³n}
\index[street]{Avenida de las fuerzas armadas}
\index[street]{Avenida del sur}
\index[street]{Calle adoratrices}
\index[street]{Calle alondra}
\index[street]{Calle arquitecto felipe gimÃ©nez lacal}
\index[street]{Calle atarfeÃ±o}
\index[street]{Calle carlos arruza}
\index[street]{Calle cartagenera}
\index[street]{Calle cruz del sur}
\index[street]{Calle curro cÃºchares}
\index[street]{Calle doctor azpitarte}
\index[street]{Calle doctor gÃ³mez romÃ¡n}
\index[street]{Calle doctor pareja yÃ©benes}
\index[street]{Calle el guerra}
\index[street]{Calle escultor pablo loyzaga}
\index[street]{Calle gallito}
\index[street]{Calle gaona}
\index[street]{Calle jesÃºs fandila}
\index[street]{Calle joaquÃ­n garcÃ­a}
\index[street]{Calle joseito de granada}
\index[street]{Calle lagartijillo}
\index[street]{Calle lubina}
\index[street]{Calle luis amador}
\index[street]{Calle machaquito}
\index[street]{Calle maestro pedro fernÃ¡ndez estÃ©vez}
\index[street]{Calle malagueÃ±a}
\index[street]{Calle manolete}
\index[street]{Calle manoletinas}
\index[street]{Calle martinetes}
\index[street]{Calle mencÃ­a calderÃ³n}
\index[street]{Calle morena}
\index[street]{Calle nuestra seÃ±ora de la salud}
\index[street]{Calle perete}
\index[street]{Calle pintor francisco pradilla}
\index[street]{Calle ribera del beiro}
\index[street]{Calle saeta}
\index[street]{Calle tercio}
\index[street]{Calle verdiales}
\index[street]{Calle yerbagÃ¼ena}
\index[street]{Camino de ronda}
\index[street]{Carretera de mÃ¡laga}
\index[street]{Plaza de la caleta}
\index[poi]{Centro de salud de la caleta}
\index[poi]{ConsejerÃ­a de salud}
\index[poi]{Hospital materno-infantil}
\index[poi]{Hospital virgen de las nieves}
\index[poi]{Luis amador}
\index[poi]{Villarejo}
\clearpage

%-------------

\thispagestyle{empty}
PAGE THREE

\index[street]{Avenida de madrid}
\index[street]{Avenida doctor olÃ³riz}
\index[street]{Avenida juan pablo ii}
\index[street]{Calle belmonte}
\index[street]{Calle cardenal parrado}
\index[street]{Calle carlos arruza}
\index[street]{Calle concepciÃ³n arenal}
\index[street]{Calle cuevas de almanzora}
\index[street]{Calle doctor adelardo mora}
\index[street]{Calle doctor azpitarte}
\index[street]{Calle doctor barraquer}
\index[street]{Calle doctor blasco reta}
\index[street]{Calle doctor castroviejo}
\index[street]{Calle doctor enrique hernÃ¡ndez}
\index[street]{Calle doctor felipe villalobos}
\index[street]{Calle doctor fermÃ­n garrido}
\index[street]{Calle doctor fernando escobar}
\index[street]{Calle doctor fidel fernÃ¡ndez}
\index[street]{Calle doctor fleming}
\index[street]{Calle doctor guirao gea}
\index[street]{Calle doctor gÃ³mez romÃ¡n}
\index[street]{Calle doctor maraÃ±Ã³n}
\index[street]{Calle doctor mesa moles}
\index[street]{Calle doctor muÃ±oz fernÃ¡ndez}
\index[street]{Calle doctor pareja yÃ©benes}
\index[street]{Calle doctor rojas ballesteros}
\index[street]{Calle doctor sÃ¡nchez mariscal}
\index[street]{Calle doctor vÃ­ctor escribano}
\index[street]{Calle enrique bernedo bojilla}
\index[street]{Calle gallito}
\index[street]{Calle gaona}
\index[street]{Calle granada club de fÃºtbol}
\index[street]{Calle hospital de san lÃ¡zaro}
\index[street]{Calle isaac albÃ©niz}
\index[street]{Calle lagartijillo}
\index[street]{Calle las madroÃ±eras}
\index[street]{Calle machaquito}
\index[street]{Calle manolete}
\index[street]{Calle manolÃ©}
\index[street]{Calle pepe hillo}
\index[street]{Calle polo y caÃ±a}
\index[street]{Calle real maestranza}
\index[street]{Calle recreativo de granada}
\index[street]{Calle ribera del beiro}
\index[street]{Calle san agapito}
\index[street]{Calle san benito}
\index[street]{Calle san fernando}
\index[street]{Calle san ignacio}
\index[street]{Calle san joaquÃ­n}
\index[street]{Calle san juan de letrÃ¡n}
\index[street]{Calle san juliÃ¡n}
\index[street]{Calle san pablo}
\index[street]{Calle santa amelia}
\index[street]{Calle verdiales}
\index[street]{Calle yerbagÃ¼ena}
\index[street]{Calle Ãlvarez pelayo}
\index[street]{Doctor pareja yÃ‰benes}
\index[street]{Glorieta victimas de la violencia de genero}
\index[street]{Placeta arquitecto Ãngel casas}
\index[street]{Placeta doctor martÃ­nez castro}
\index[street]{Plaza de la caleta}
\index[street]{Plaza de la ciudad de los cÃ¡rmenes}
\index[street]{Plaza de san pantaleÃ³n}
\index[street]{Plaza del doctor lÃ³pez neyra}
\index[street]{Plaza doctor lopez}
\index[street]{Ribera del beiro}
\index[poi]{Hospital materno-infantil}
\index[poi]{Hospital universitario san cecilio}
\index[poi]{Hospital virgen de las nieves}
\index[poi]{Urgencias hospital clinico}
\index[poi]{Escuela universitaria de ciencias de la salud}
\index[poi]{Antigua prisiÃ³n provincial de granada}
\index[poi]{Plaza monumental de toros}
\clearpage

%-------------

\thispagestyle{empty}
PAGE FOUR

\index[street]{Avenida de madrid}
\index[street]{Avenida de murcia}
\index[street]{Avenida de pulianas}
\index[street]{Calle abanilla}
\index[street]{Calle acosta inglot}
\index[street]{Calle agua de cartuja}
\index[street]{Calle alta de cartuja}
\index[street]{Calle alvaro aparicio}
\index[street]{Calle beniel}
\index[street]{Calle cardenal parrado}
\index[street]{Calle castro cortÃ©s}
\index[street]{Calle cazorla}
\index[street]{Calle cieza}
\index[street]{Calle concepciÃ³n arenal}
\index[street]{Calle cristo de la yedra}
\index[street]{Calle doctor jimÃ©nez garrido}
\index[street]{Calle domingo lozano}
\index[street]{Calle eras de cristo}
\index[street]{Calle garcia morato}
\index[street]{Calle garcÃ­a villatoro}
\index[street]{Calle granada club de fÃºtbol}
\index[street]{Calle josÃ© morell}
\index[street]{Calle labella dÃ¡valos}
\index[street]{Calle pizarro cenjor}
\index[street]{Calle profesor clavera}
\index[street]{Calle profesor vicente callao}
\index[street]{Calle real de cartuja}
\index[street]{Calle recreativo de granada}
\index[street]{Calle ribera del beiro}
\index[street]{Calle san agapito}
\index[street]{Calle san benito}
\index[street]{Calle totana}
\index[street]{Calle turia}
\index[street]{Calle virgen del pilar}
\index[street]{Calle yeseros}
\index[street]{CallejÃ³n de lebrija}
\index[street]{CallejÃ³n poco trigo}
\index[street]{Carretera de murcia}
\index[street]{Paseo de cartuja}
\index[street]{Placeta de aljucer}
\index[street]{Placeta santomera}
\index[street]{Plaza almagro segura}
\index[street]{Plaza de la ciudad de los cÃ¡rmenes}
\index[street]{Plaza del cardenal cisneros}
\index[poi]{Hospital universitario san cecilio}
\index[poi]{Facultad de ciencias de la educaciÃ³n}
\index[poi]{Universidad de granada - campus de cartuja}
\index[poi]{Monasterio de la cartuja}
\clearpage


\printindex[street]
\printindex[poi]

\end{document}
```

**Compiled with:**

```
xelatex test.tex
```

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main error is in breaking the line with `%` in the `.ist` file.

Here's a fixed version.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{index.ist}
preamble "\\begin{theindex}\\small\\raggedright"
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\n{\\centering\\large\\sffamily\\noindent\\textbf{"heading_suffix "}\\par}\\nopagebreak\n"

item_0 "\n\\item "

delim_0 "\\betterdotfill "
delim_1 "\\betterdotfill "
delim_2 "\\betterdotfill " 
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[8pt,twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx,grffile}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[paperwidth=5.125in, 
            paperheight=8.25in, 
            bindingoffset=0.1in,
            inner=0.6in,
            outer=0.7in,
            top=0.6in,
            bottom=1in,
            columnsep=25pt,
            layoutsize={5in,8in},
            layouthoffset=0.125in,
            layoutvoffset=0.25in
            ]
            {geometry}

\usepackage[nobottomtitles*]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=street,title=Streets,options=-s ./index]
\makeindex[name=poi,title=Points of Interest,options=-s ./index]

\usepackage[font=small]{idxlayout}

\makeatletter
\def\@idxitem{\par\hangindent 0pt}
\newcommand{\betterdotfill}{%
  \leavevmode \nobreak\cleaders \hb@xt@ .44em{\hss .\hss }\hskip .5em plus 1fill \kern \z@ 
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
PAGE ONE

\index[street]{Avenida de andaluc√≠a}
\index[street]{Avenida de francisco ayala}
\index[street]{Avenida de las alpujarras}
\index[street]{Avenida luis miranda d√°valos}
\index[street]{Calle adoratrices}
\index[street]{Calle algarrobo}
\index[street]{Calle algas}
\index[street]{Calle antonio machado}
\index[street]{Calle apolo}
\index[street]{Calle baza}
\index[street]{Calle brindis}
\index[street]{Calle capote}
\index[street]{Calle chanquete}
\index[street]{Calle chicuelinas}
\index[street]{Calle circunvalaci√≥n encina}
\index[street]{Calle coso}
\index[street]{Calle curro c√∫chares}
\index[street]{Calle delf√≠n}
\index[street]{Calle dorada}
\index[street]{Calle encina}
\index[street]{Calle este}
\index[street]{Calle esturi√≥n}
\index[street]{Calle guadix}
\index[street]{Calle hispanidad}
\index[street]{Calle joseito de granada}
\index[street]{Calle j√∫piter}
\index[street]{Calle las acacias}
\index[street]{Calle manuel mateos}
\index[street]{Calle mar√≠a lej√°rraga}
\index[street]{Calle mero}
\index[street]{Calle monosabio}
\index[street]{Calle morena}
\index[street]{Calle mulillas}
\index[street]{Calle nervi√≥n}
\index[street]{Calle norte}
\index[street]{Calle oeste}
\index[street]{Calle pargo}
\index[street]{Calle perete}
\index[street]{Calle periodista antonio l√≥pez mu√±oz}
\index[street]{Calle periodista eduardo font moreno}
\index[street]{Calle periodista fernando g√≥mez de la cruz}
\index[street]{Calle periodista francisco guerrero v√≠lchez}
\index[street]{Calle periodista francisco javier cobos}
\index[street]{Calle periodista gabriel ruiz de almod√≥var}
\index[street]{Calle periodista mat√≠as m√©ndez vellido}
\index[street]{Calle periodista miguel montalvo jim√©nez}
\index[street]{Calle periodista ricardo l√≥pez jofre}
\index[street]{Calle raya}
\index[street]{Calle rej√≥n}
\index[street]{Calle salm√≥n}
\index[street]{Calle sirena}
\index[street]{Calle sur}
\index[street]{Calle te√≥filo gautier}
\index[street]{Calle tibur√≥n}
\index[street]{Calle trucha}
\index[street]{Calle veleta}
\index[street]{Calle venus}
\index[street]{Carretera de m√°laga}
\index[street]{Plaza periodista jos√© mar√≠a gonzalo de la torre}
\index[street]{Plaza periodista ram√≥n maurell l√≥pez}
\clearpage

%-------------

\thispagestyle{empty}
PAGE TWO

\index[street]{Avenida de andaluc√≠a}
\index[street]{Avenida de francisco ayala}
\index[street]{Avenida de la constituci√≥n}
\index[street]{Avenida de las fuerzas armadas}
\index[street]{Avenida del sur}
\index[street]{Calle adoratrices}
\index[street]{Calle alondra}
\index[street]{Calle arquitecto felipe gim√©nez lacal}
\index[street]{Calle atarfe√±o}
\index[street]{Calle carlos arruza}
\index[street]{Calle cartagenera}
\index[street]{Calle cruz del sur}
\index[street]{Calle curro c√∫chares}
\index[street]{Calle doctor azpitarte}
\index[street]{Calle doctor g√≥mez rom√°n}
\index[street]{Calle doctor pareja y√©benes}
\index[street]{Calle el guerra}
\index[street]{Calle escultor pablo loyzaga}
\index[street]{Calle gallito}
\index[street]{Calle gaona}
\index[street]{Calle jes√∫s fandila}
\index[street]{Calle joaqu√≠n garc√≠a}
\index[street]{Calle joseito de granada}
\index[street]{Calle lagartijillo}
\index[street]{Calle lubina}
\index[street]{Calle luis amador}
\index[street]{Calle machaquito}
\index[street]{Calle maestro pedro fern√°ndez est√©vez}
\index[street]{Calle malague√±a}
\index[street]{Calle manolete}
\index[street]{Calle manoletinas}
\index[street]{Calle martinetes}
\index[street]{Calle menc√≠a calder√≥n}
\index[street]{Calle morena}
\index[street]{Calle nuestra se√±ora de la salud}
\index[street]{Calle perete}
\index[street]{Calle pintor francisco pradilla}
\index[street]{Calle ribera del beiro}
\index[street]{Calle saeta}
\index[street]{Calle tercio}
\index[street]{Calle verdiales}
\index[street]{Calle yerbag√ºena}
\index[street]{Camino de ronda}
\index[street]{Carretera de m√°laga}
\index[street]{Plaza de la caleta}
\index[poi]{Centro de salud de la caleta}
\index[poi]{Consejer√≠a de salud}
\index[poi]{Hospital materno-infantil}
\index[poi]{Hospital virgen de las nieves}
\index[poi]{Luis amador}
\index[poi]{Villarejo}
\clearpage

%-------------

\thispagestyle{empty}
PAGE THREE

\index[street]{Avenida de madrid}
\index[street]{Avenida doctor ol√≥riz}
\index[street]{Avenida juan pablo ii}
\index[street]{Calle belmonte}
\index[street]{Calle cardenal parrado}
\index[street]{Calle carlos arruza}
\index[street]{Calle concepci√≥n arenal}
\index[street]{Calle cuevas de almanzora}
\index[street]{Calle doctor adelardo mora}
\index[street]{Calle doctor azpitarte}
\index[street]{Calle doctor barraquer}
\index[street]{Calle doctor blasco reta}
\index[street]{Calle doctor castroviejo}
\index[street]{Calle doctor enrique hern√°ndez}
\index[street]{Calle doctor felipe villalobos}
\index[street]{Calle doctor ferm√≠n garrido}
\index[street]{Calle doctor fernando escobar}
\index[street]{Calle doctor fidel fern√°ndez}
\index[street]{Calle doctor fleming}
\index[street]{Calle doctor guirao gea}
\index[street]{Calle doctor g√≥mez rom√°n}
\index[street]{Calle doctor mara√±√≥n}
\index[street]{Calle doctor mesa moles}
\index[street]{Calle doctor mu√±oz fern√°ndez}
\index[street]{Calle doctor pareja y√©benes}
\index[street]{Calle doctor rojas ballesteros}
\index[street]{Calle doctor s√°nchez mariscal}
\index[street]{Calle doctor v√≠ctor escribano}
\index[street]{Calle enrique bernedo bojilla}
\index[street]{Calle gallito}
\index[street]{Calle gaona}
\index[street]{Calle granada club de f√∫tbol}
\index[street]{Calle hospital de san l√°zaro}
\index[street]{Calle isaac alb√©niz}
\index[street]{Calle lagartijillo}
\index[street]{Calle las madro√±eras}
\index[street]{Calle machaquito}
\index[street]{Calle manolete}
\index[street]{Calle manol√©}
\index[street]{Calle pepe hillo}
\index[street]{Calle polo y ca√±a}
\index[street]{Calle real maestranza}
\index[street]{Calle recreativo de granada}
\index[street]{Calle ribera del beiro}
\index[street]{Calle san agapito}
\index[street]{Calle san benito}
\index[street]{Calle san fernando}
\index[street]{Calle san ignacio}
\index[street]{Calle san joaqu√≠n}
\index[street]{Calle san juan de letr√°n}
\index[street]{Calle san juli√°n}
\index[street]{Calle san pablo}
\index[street]{Calle santa amelia}
\index[street]{Calle verdiales}
\index[street]{Calle yerbag√ºena}
\index[street]{Calle √°lvarez pelayo}
\index[street]{Doctor pareja y√©benes}
\index[street]{Glorieta victimas de la violencia de genero}
\index[street]{Placeta arquitecto √°ngel casas}
\index[street]{Placeta doctor mart√≠nez castro}
\index[street]{Plaza de la caleta}
\index[street]{Plaza de la ciudad de los c√°rmenes}
\index[street]{Plaza de san pantale√≥n}
\index[street]{Plaza del doctor l√≥pez neyra}
\index[street]{Plaza doctor lopez}
\index[street]{Ribera del beiro}
\index[poi]{Hospital materno-infantil}
\index[poi]{Hospital universitario san cecilio}
\index[poi]{Hospital virgen de las nieves}
\index[poi]{Urgencias hospital clinico}
\index[poi]{Escuela universitaria de ciencias de la salud}
\index[poi]{Antigua prisi√≥n provincial de granada}
\index[poi]{Plaza monumental de toros}
\clearpage

%-------------

\thispagestyle{empty}
PAGE FOUR

\index[street]{Avenida de madrid}
\index[street]{Avenida de murcia}
\index[street]{Avenida de pulianas}
\index[street]{Calle abanilla}
\index[street]{Calle acosta inglot}
\index[street]{Calle agua de cartuja}
\index[street]{Calle alta de cartuja}
\index[street]{Calle alvaro aparicio}
\index[street]{Calle beniel}
\index[street]{Calle cardenal parrado}
\index[street]{Calle castro cort√©s}
\index[street]{Calle cazorla}
\index[street]{Calle cieza}
\index[street]{Calle concepci√≥n arenal}
\index[street]{Calle cristo de la yedra}
\index[street]{Calle doctor jim√©nez garrido}
\index[street]{Calle domingo lozano}
\index[street]{Calle eras de cristo}
\index[street]{Calle garcia morato}
\index[street]{Calle garc√≠a villatoro}
\index[street]{Calle granada club de f√∫tbol}
\index[street]{Calle jos√© morell}
\index[street]{Calle labella d√°valos}
\index[street]{Calle pizarro cenjor}
\index[street]{Calle profesor clavera}
\index[street]{Calle profesor vicente callao}
\index[street]{Calle real de cartuja}
\index[street]{Calle recreativo de granada}
\index[street]{Calle ribera del beiro}
\index[street]{Calle san agapito}
\index[street]{Calle san benito}
\index[street]{Calle totana}
\index[street]{Calle turia}
\index[street]{Calle virgen del pilar}
\index[street]{Calle yeseros}
\index[street]{Callej√≥n de lebrija}
\index[street]{Callej√≥n poco trigo}
\index[street]{Carretera de murcia}
\index[street]{Paseo de cartuja}
\index[street]{Placeta de aljucer}
\index[street]{Placeta santomera}
\index[street]{Plaza almagro segura}
\index[street]{Plaza de la ciudad de los c√°rmenes}
\index[street]{Plaza del cardenal cisneros}
\index[poi]{Hospital universitario san cecilio}
\index[poi]{Facultad de ciencias de la educaci√≥n}
\index[poi]{Universidad de granada - campus de cartuja}
\index[poi]{Monasterio de la cartuja}
\clearpage


\printindex[street]
\printindex[poi]

\end{document}
```

I used the `filecontents*` environment for making the example self-contained. The calls to `inputenc` and `fontenc` have been removed, because they don't belong in documents using `fontspec`.

I also used `\betterdotfill` to ensure no page number falls at the left side, which can happen with `\dotfill` if the entry is too long. Honestly, I'd hang the broken lines, but that's your choice.

Instead of issuing `\small` for every entry, I stated `\small` at the beginning of the index.

[image]